# How use system default icons pack in Java Swing?

Tags: java, linux, swing, intellij-idea, gnome

I want use the default icons of my OS (kali linux gnome) in my Java application. I don't know if need to import the entire icons pack or if i just use some java swing method.
Can you explain to me how to proceed?

Comment: Short version: `Icon icon = new ImageIcon("/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/32x32/actions/document-open.png");`  Long version:  Parse the [theme file](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html).  I don’t know if there exists a library to make it easier.

Comment: @VGR It works, thank you. Reply to the post if you want me to mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to just use an icon file directly:

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon("/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/32x32/actions/document-open.png");
```

But really, icons are more complicated than that.  There is [a whole specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html) for how icon themes work.  It includes a moderately complex algorithm for matching a desired icon by type and size.

Java SE has no way to read SVG images that I know of, so either you would need to locate a robust, stable SVG library for Java, or you would need to ignore a theme’s scalable directories.

The only way I know to obtain the end user’s current icon theme is with a command like:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "gsettings", "get", "org.gnome.desktop.interface", "icon-theme");
builder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

String themeName;
Process iconThemeCommand = builder.start();
try (InputStream commandOutput = iconThemeCommand.getInputStream()) {
    themeName = new String(commandOutput.readAllBytes()).trim();
}
iconThemeCommand.waitFor();
```

There is also the problem of being multi-platform.  Obviously Windows and OSX won’t have a `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita` directory.  You can bundle an icon theme tree with your application, but it’s probably under GPL or a similar license, so you would have to release your software under that license (or never release it at all) and include a copy of that license with your program, along with a notice to users where to obtain your program’s source.

Comment: The system(ish) icons should be used by the system PLAF, and that will be robust across OS'.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure if this is what you are asking but these will set the look and feel OS specific:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```